# How to make regular backups with TeamViewer?

Tags: backup, remote-desktop, dropbox, teamviewer, matlab

I have to use a remote computer for a computational project in MATLAB. Therefore I connect to it via TeamViewer, and run my codes in that machine. But I also want to write the code on my computer, and upload to it. So every time I have to copy paste source files to and from Dropbox.

Maybe I could set the same folder for both Dropbox and MATLAB, but I'm also afraid of deleting something accidentally. So can I make a scheduled back up of the files on the remote computer? Or any other solutions to this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sure; You can do that what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing because I don't know which software to use. By regular back up I mean automating the process.

Comment: Is this a software recommendations question? Use a program such as [Bvckup - last beta is free](https://bvckup2.com/) to make backup of the folders you want to keep copies of.